# Wrapper functions for terminal capabilities

Tags: c, console, unix

I've prepared a small C interface so the rest of my program can access relevant system functions.  I am not a C programmer, though - just C++ and D, mainly.  I want to make sure that everything here is "C-ish" before committing the rest of my code to this interface.

This is just a plain old C file, compiled with a C compiler (as opposed to C++).

```
    /*
     * This file provides functions to interface with
     * low-level terminal properties such as size and
     * input modes.  Functions meant to be accessible
     * to external "user" code begin with "Terminal."
     */

#include <sys/ioctl.h> // For interfacing with the terminal device.
#include <termios.h> // Ditto.
#include <unistd.h> // For the STDIN_FILENO file descriptor macro.

// This is just used internally, and should not be called directly from D code.
struct winsize Size()
{
    struct winsize Size;
    ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, TIOCGWINSZ, &Size);
    return Size;
}

unsigned short int TerminalColumnCount()
{
    return Size().ws_col;
}

unsigned short int TerminalRowCount()
{
    return Size().ws_row;
}

// Used to reset the terminal properties to their original state.
// Again, this is only for internal use.
struct termios BackupProperties;

// Removes terminal input buffering so programs can see typed characters before Enter is pressed.
void TerminalMakeRaw() // I wish I could come up with a better name for this.  
{
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &BackupProperties);
    struct termios NewProperties;
    cfmakeraw(&NewProperties);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &NewProperties);
}

void TerminalReset()
{
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &BackupProperties);
}
```

Comment: If you're compiling this with a C++ compiler, don't forget to use `extern "C"`.

Comment: @MartinhoFernandes It's just a plain C file, compiled with `gcc`.  I'll edit that into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few quick comments:

- You should declare all internal functions and variables `static` to avoid polluting the global namespace. (You'd do this in a C++ program as well, but would probably use an unnamed namespace. I'm not sure what the D equivalent is).
- Since you have state (implicitly and explicitly via `BackupProperties`) I'd recommend using an object oriented approach exposing an [opaque pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C) to maintain it, even if there is only one `Terminal` instance it's (IMO) a better approach. Otherwise you should at least ensure that `TerminalMakeRaw` isn't called twice without corresponding calls to `TerminalReset`.
- You should also consider that at some point you'll probably want to have callbacks of some sort to notify the users of your library when/if the window size changes and so on.

Comment: Pertaining to your second suggestion, I ended up going with a global state solution.  I'm aware that it's often considered bad practice, but in this case I think it makes sense and I'm not going to overcomplicate things just on principle.

Comment: @Maxpm: As long as you're making an informed decision it's fine by me :)